# ADMOB banner ads messing with screen size and width

Tags: android, libgdx, admob

So, I'm trying to add banner ads to my android app, which I used LibGDX to create. I followed this tutorial to add banner ads:

https://github.com/TheInvader360/tutorial-libgdx-google-ads/blob/9a4c9342d98c02e3c44e0b62fcfaa153d257130a/tutorial-libgdx-google-ads-android/src/com/theinvader360/tutorial/libgdx/google/ads/MainActivity.java

Now, I have an input listener that checks a certain width and height when the user clicks buttons. When I implemented the ads, my x and y coordinates were shifted. I was wondering if there was a way to show the ads on top of the screen, other than wrapping the content.

** When I say on top of the screen, my game is running, and the ads are running on top of the game, not shifting of coordinates. \

Thanks!

Comment: Show us your code, else we can't guess what you have done wrong. Show us a minimal working example, or show us your current "short" code and a picture whats going wrong if you can make a picture.

Comment: I don't understand, the code is in the link, mine is identical. What is happening, when I test it without ads, the height of the app is 1280px, when I run the ads, its 1180px, how do I make it that it does not change the px (it stays to 1280px, as if there was no ads, i don't want the ads to change anything, just display)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following from createGameView:

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, adView.getId());
```

Then add the gameView to the layout before the adView, so the ad will be atop the game.

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed it!